# Linq statement query, possible group

Tags: c#, linq

Can this all be done in one linq statement query? Or should I make the existing call and then filter?

I have a requirement to return a list of access tokens that will be expiring soon.

If there are two tokens for the same applicationName. For example "Test 3" 
Then do not return the a token if there is already another token that won't be expiring soon.

So based on the example provided below, If i wanted all of the tokens that are expiring within 15 days, no records should be returned.

cccDDD888 is expiring in 10 days but eeeFFF999 is a new token for the same application.

```
            return new List<Domain.Models.AccessToken>
               {
                   new Domain.Models.AccessToken {ApplicationName = "Test", ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(100), Id = new Guid("943e31bd-7c91-44bf-9ee2-3366c9f5010c"), Token = "aaaBBB111"},
                   new Domain.Models.AccessToken {ApplicationName = "Test 2", ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(50), Id = new Guid("cc1cec9b-7de6-46e7-8069-5681c8d2d331"), Token = "xxxYYY777"},
                   new Domain.Models.AccessToken {ApplicationName = "Test 3", ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10), Id = new Guid("da5343da-e2c4-477c-b3ed-b60133512f5d"), Token = "cccDDD888"},
                   new Domain.Models.AccessToken {ApplicationName = "Test 3", ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365), Id = new Guid("7d7556d8-e194-43be-89ce-0961fc94ebd4"), Token = "eeeFFF999"},
                   new Domain.Models.AccessToken {ApplicationName = "Test 4", ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), Id = new Guid("0de8a36f-a249-4df1-a5c5-fbaf26e32bb2"), Token = "jjjKKK444"},
               };
```

Comment: The best method depends on how the database is storing the data.  You have to check if there is a primary key for the database and then use the Primary key as the first lookup in the query.  Primary Keys are hash lookup that will speed up the query time.

Comment: Yes, each token as a primary key. 
My plan so far was to check for all tokens expiring within a set period of days.
If is a token is returned, make another query to see if there is another token for that same application that is not expiring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
var allTokens = new List<AccessToken>
    {
        new Domain.Models.AccessToken {ApplicationName = "Test", ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(100), Id = new Guid("943e31bd-7c91-44bf-9ee2-3366c9f5010c"), Token = "aaaBBB111"},
        new Domain.Models.AccessToken {ApplicationName = "Test 2", ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(50), Id = new Guid("cc1cec9b-7de6-46e7-8069-5681c8d2d331"), Token = "xxxYYY777"},
        new Domain.Models.AccessToken {ApplicationName = "Test 3", ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10), Id = new Guid("da5343da-e2c4-477c-b3ed-b60133512f5d"), Token = "cccDDD888"},
        new Domain.Models.AccessToken {ApplicationName = "Test 3", ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365), Id = new Guid("7d7556d8-e194-43be-89ce-0961fc94ebd4"), Token = "eeeFFF999"},
        new Domain.Models.AccessToken {ApplicationName = "Test 4", ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), Id = new Guid("0de8a36f-a249-4df1-a5c5-fbaf26e32bb2"), Token = "jjjKKK444"},
    };

var expiringThresholdInDays = 15;
var expirationDeadLine = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(expiringThresholdInDays);
var expiringTokens = allTokens.GroupBy(a => a.ApplicationName).Where(b => b.OrderByDescending(x => x.ExpirationDate).FirstOrDefault().ExpirationDate < expirationDeadLine);
```

However, this will return Test 4's token, which already expired. If you want to exclude the already expired tokens, change the last line to this:

```
var expiringTokens = allTokens.GroupBy(a => a.ApplicationName).Where(b =>
{
    var expirationDate = b.OrderByDescending(x => x.ExpirationDate).FirstOrDefault().ExpirationDate;
    return System.DateTime.Now < expirationDate && expirationDate < expirationDeadLine;
});
```

Comment: In the example I provided, no access tokens should be returned.
The applicationName = "Test 3" does have an expiring token that meets the criteria.

However, there is another token for "Test 3" that is not expiring. @burkay

Comment: Yes, as you wanted, none of the above options returns Test 3. First one returns Test 4, because it already expired. If you don't want it either, you can use the second one. If this solved your question, please mark it as answer:) @JasonJay